# facebook api calling offline

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying facebok api.
For that I created a app-key.
and wrote a small programm. installed apache and executed that HTML file.
The facebook logo comes but I am not able to fetch any values from that program.
if I execute the same program on facebook console it works and gives the values.

is it not possible to usethe facebook api on a local machine connected to internet but in a private IP.? I dont want to directly work on my server. want to test a few things offline on my machine and than deploy the code..is it not possible>

Is there a better way to print the frdslist using java API in facebook apis

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My  Test Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxx', // App ID
        channelUrl : 'sample.com/backup', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };                  
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";         
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));


   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
var img_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture"
```

});

```
     FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'name,id,location,birthday' }, function(result) {

})


  </script>


   <div class="fb-login-button" >Login with Facebook</div>


</body>
```

Comment: If facebook is accessible from local machine then it should work fine. Can you post some code.

Comment: Can you pl let me know if anything else need to be done to run this locally.

Answer (score 0):

Add "read_friendlist" permission.

Comment: Also, can I be able to run the same above program on my local machine running apache. I want to run it before I deploy in the live network. o for my basic testing I am trying to run locally but it is not working. but in facebook console it works